# Comparing integers in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to get all Dna-entities with status (INT) 1,2,3,4 but Eclipselink is giving me error.

> ReadAllQuery(name="Dna.findAllButDeleted" referenceClass=Dna jpql="SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status =1 OR r.status=2 OR r.status=3 OR r.status=4")

```
@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Dna> findAllButDeleted(){
   System.out.println("**********findAllButDeleted*************");
    Query query =  em.createNamedQuery("Dna.findAllButDeleted");
    List<Dna> lista = query.getResultList();
    return lista;
}

@NamedQuery(name = "Dna.findAllButDeleted", query = "SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status =1 OR r.status=2 OR r.status=3 OR r.status=4"),
```

**ERROR**

> Exception [EclipseLink-6078] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
>   Exception Description: The class of the argument for the object comparison is incorrect. 
>   Expression: [
>   Base com.pako.entity.Dna] 
>   Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[status]] 
>   Argument: [1]

EDIT:
My mistake, now I see the problem. In Dna entity status is not integer but object. How to use multiple parameters? It seems that it is using only the last one.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Dnastatus status;

   Dnastatus oneStatus = new Dnastatus(new Integer(1));
   Dnastatus twoStatus = new Dnastatus(new Integer(2));
   Dnastatus threeStatus = new Dnastatus(new Integer(3));

   Query query =  em.createNamedQuery("Dna.findAllButDeleted").
            setParameter("status", oneStatus).
            setParameter("status", twoStatus).
            setParameter("status", threeStatus);
@NamedQuery(name = "Dna.findAllButDeleted", query = "SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status = :status"),
```

EDIT2:
**Solution**

```
   List statusList = new ArrayList();
   statusList.add(oneStatus);
   statusList.add(twoStatus);
   statusList.add(threeStatus);
   statusList.add(fourStatus);

Query query =  em.createNamedQuery("Dna.findAllButDeleted").
            setParameter("statusList", statusList);
@NamedQuery(name = "Dna.findAllButDeleted", query = "SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status IN (:statusList)")
```

Comment: Show the `Dna` entity.

Comment: Y u r not using query like   `@NamedQuery(name = "Dna.findAllButDeleted", query = "SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status In (1,2,3,4)"),`

Comment: Showing the field "status" of class "Dna" is a prerequisite for any comment. EclipseLink clearly thinks its a N-1 relation field, so cannot be an integer. So why not show it ?

Comment: My mistake, status is an object, not int anywhere else than in DB.

Comment: Why are you setting the parameter "status" 3 times? The final value will be used if you do that. Would make more sense to put a List as the single parameter, and that list contain 3 values of type Dnastatus, and use "IN"

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too much in SQL which is exactly how JPA will be your worst enemy. Status may be an int in the database, but in your entities it is a separate Status object linked in a ManyToOne annotation - the error explains exactly that. So the JPQL with a hard integer check would be something like:

```
SELECT r FROM Dna r where r.status.id in 1,2,3,4
```

Assuming the id column of the Status entity is named 'id'; adjust to whatever you're using.

Just to note: I wouldn't use this code myself, queries with magic numbers are bad for readability. You can't see what status 1-4 actually are without having to go look in the database first.

Comment: So I have to go to DB first and fetch Status-objects and use them in namedQuery? Could you pls teach me how to do it?

Comment: Easier way could be fetch NOT status 5, but is this possible with JPQL?

Comment: @Sami that is what books are for, not SO